# What determines how different CLIs format their parameters?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

For example, why do you have to use the --version flag/command to check a Python version, whereas you can use -v to check the version on a local NodeJS install?

What determines and/or distinguishes this? Is there a set of standards or is it up to the CLI developer to establish his/her own conventions? Is it based on some abstraction from low-level machine languages? Is it random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is it up to the CLI developer to establish his/her own conventions?

Pretty much yes. Developers, however, usually do try to be consistent with previously used command line options in similar programs where possible.

Notes:

- You can use `-V` (upper case) on a python command line to display the version

> `-V`
>
> `--version`
>
> Print the Python version number and exit.

- The python command line uses `-v` (lower case) to enable Verbose:

> `-v`
>
> Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place
>   (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When given
>   twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for when
>   searching for a module. Also provides information on module cleanup at
>   exit.

Source [1. Command line and environment — Python 3.7.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

- You can also use `--version` in `nodejs`

> `-v, --version`
>
> Added in: v0.1.3
>
> Print node's version.

Source [Command Line Options | Node.js v12.6.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_v_version)

---

## Further Reading

- [coding style - Are there standards for Linux command line switches and arguments?    - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957222/are-there-standards-for-linux-command-line-switches-and-arguments)
- [The Art of Unix Programming - Command-Line Options](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html)
- [Command line arguments order - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336192/command-line-arguments-order)